# NixOs Attribute Error with unstable package on stable release

Tags: nixos, nix

I’m trying to install [material shell](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=unstable&show=gnomeExtensions.material-shell&from=0&size=30&sort=relevance&query=material+shell) which is only in unstable right now.

I’m using the [guide from the wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_install_a_package_from_unstable_while_remaining_on_the_stable_channel.3F) to install a package from unstable along with this [post on adding unstable without using a channel](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/installing-only-a-single-package-from-unstable/5598/4?u=ciferkey).

The configuration looks like:

```
let
  unstableTarball =
    fetchTarball
      https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz;
in
{

  nixpkgs.config = {
    packageOverrides = pkgs: {
      unstable = import unstableTarball {
        config = config.nixpkgs.config;
      };
    };
  };

  # List packages installed in system profile. To search, run:
  # $ nix search wget
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    unstable.gnomeExtensions.material-shell
  ];

}
```

I am able to install gnome extensions from 20.09 with no errors.
I am able to install packages from unstable with no errors.
When I try to install “unstable.gnomeExtensions.material-shell” I get the following build error:

```
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: attribute 'material-shell' missing, at /cfg/configuration.nix:102:5
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I’ve tried installing through both environment.systemPackages in my configuration.nix and my home.packages in my home.nix.

Do I need to use a different package name to get this to work?

Comment: Did you update the unstable channel? For NixOS configuration, you will need to update it with `sudo`.

Comment: I've added some more detail to clarify. I'm using the unstable tarball in the configuration rather than setting the channel up outside my configuration.nix. A full example is now in the post.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels repository has been deprecated and is no longer updated; the channel branches are now part of the main repo. You will need to switch to https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz

Comment: This resolved the issue! Thanks.